# Searching an algorithm of Counter propagation neural network

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

Im running through the Internet, and I can't find any algorithm of counter-propagation neural network or any info about it.

Actually I need to use it in my school project, where I import the data from txt file(mostly strings) and then set the amount of neurons on every hidden layer.

Does anybody know something about that type of neural network?

Comment: *"Does anybody know something about ...?"* Yes, I'm sure somebody does, but presumably that is not what you actually wanted to ask. Please see [ask] and edit in order to ask a specific question.

Comment: Is it possible that you mean backpropagation? You will at least get web search results for that, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation